# What are the legitimate use cases of the tag property?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Are there any legitimate uses of the `tag` property of a view? In the cases I have encountered where using a tag might solve a problem, an alternative (and less [smelly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell)) solution has been found.

In other words, if Apple were to deprecate the `tag` property, what would your objections be?

Comment: Your question is not clear.  What uses do you already know about and what is the less "smelly" solution?

Comment: Even a custom View does not have a tag property!!!

Comment: The button would call `-(void)buttonTapped:(id)sender` and then I'd cast sender as a (UIButton*) and look at its title.

Comment: @user1394965 : **tag property of a view** not of buttons.

Comment: @Andy And what happens when your app is translated into German?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya `UIButton` subclasses `UIView`.

Comment: @trojanfoe :) yes I agree, UIResponder <- UIView <- UIButton. So can the answer be same as for UIButton?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya I don't even know what the *question* is, so there is no answer...

Comment: @Andy I would say that checking the button title smells more than using the tag, but that is perhaps a matter of *taste*.

Comment: @trojanfoe: What I understood is that, he want to know "What is the purpose of `tag` in UIView, as he can access it using IBOutlets. Also does accessing UIView with `tag` makes a code-smell?"

Comment: @trojanfoe Button title is set to be a localised string, in the button's action method I can set the newly created uiviewcontroller's title property to ((UIButton*)sender).titleLabel.text

Comment: @Andy: Kindly comment on my understanding of your question.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya That isn't what he asked though; he said (paraphrased) "I've seen the tag property used but I know of a better way".  However there are no more details other than his comment about using the title of a button to identify it, which to my mind smells a great deal.

Comment: @trojanfoe  I think the question is clear. Can you give a use case of the tag property that is not improved by a method that does not use the tag property (e.g. subclassing the view)

Comment: @Andy And you think that implementation "smells" less that using a number which is cheap and easy to compare?  UPDATE: No the question is not clear.

Comment: I think using the tag property is a cheap and lazy alternative to creating cleaner and more readable code (e.g. subclassing). I'd to know if I'm wrong - happy to discover I am.

Comment: @Andy Then you need to give concrete examples that use a tag in your question and allow others to provide better approaches.  Your question is too open-ended and it's going nowhere, as you can see.

Comment: @trojanfoe I don't have an example of a use cases where the `tag` property was used that couldn't be improved with a better approach ***That's why I asked this question***.

Comment: @Andy we are going round in circles. Do you feel you got the answers you wanted?  If not, do you feel that the structure of the question has anything to do with it?  If you don't like using tags then don't use them.  If you come across a problem that can only be solved by using tags, then use them.  The world will keep turning either way.

Comment: @trojanfoe Updated my question. No I have not yet received the answer I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

When using an `IBOutletCollection`, and needing to retrieve a particular instance of subviews.
I agree that : if you need that specific instance, why didn't you use a dedicated property in the first time.
Although, when prototyping applications, let's say I'm doing a Storyboard, with a tableView, using storyboard 'prototype' UITableViewCell. I can add subviews to this cell, then access them through UIView 's `viewWithTag:` in my tableView's datasource methods. I don't have to subclass `UITableViewCell`, just retrieve the prototype, and find its subviews through tag I previously set in Interface-Builder.

But I agree with you this is still kind of smelly...

I'm looking for a case where you would **need** the tag, with no other solution...
But I think you can perfectly live without using tags :)

**EDIT**:

As others pointed out, there's also the case when you have soooo many views that handling different methods for each of them (property/actions) is a pain, and tags enable you to use a single method.

Comment: I'm a hard line anti-`tag`ger but I think two original points are great uses.

Answer (score 1):

Consider that you are making a simple Calculator app. You have more than 25 buttons. If there were no 'tag' property you would have needed 25 IBActions for each of the buttons.

Similar is true for alert views as well. Tag property is one of the great attribute of UIView classes.

Comment: You could just as easily have outlets for the buttons and compare object identity. That code would be far more readable and this would be easier to set up in IB

Comment: Hey as I mentioned Im specifically speaking about a calculator app. You can have 9 buttons and single IBAction for each of these. Tags can be given from 1-9 ?? what about this. Or you still prefer writing cumbersome code for naming??

Comment: I said outlet, not action. In the cAse of numerical keys I guess it's not too bad. But, for all keys? Which is more readable - `if (sender.tag == 678)` or `if (sender == self.plusKey)`? Which is easier to maintain in IB?

Comment: Agree with you on that. As for question that has been posted , the person was looking for a single legitimate case where he could find the tag property to be useful.

Comment: I don't know if I'd say legitimate ;) but not so bad :) and good call on the question's literal meaning!